# two short beeps

Tags: desktop-computer

i put together a pc with these 4 items and a laptop 2.5" harddrive

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003ZDJ42O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZDJ42O)

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004KZDV8E](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004KZDV8E)

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003THQS20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003THQS20)

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009JDTWVC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009JDTWVC)

i have been hearing this constant beepping. it's two short beeps every 10-15 minutes, even when the pc is off. checked the mobo manual, doesnt say any thing about beeps.

Answer (score 0):

Off hand I'd say it might be a chassis intrusion alert - have you connected the chassis intrusion header correctly or is it possibly shorting out? If it's beeping when powered off I suspect that would be the root cause.

Comment: the manual doesn't say anything about this chassis intrusion thingy. http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z(h)77n-wifi_e.pdf i left a lot of stuff unplug for the case due to laziness. could that be it?